# Making a single number per line pyramid using nested loop and trying to center it

Tags: java

I have to create a number pyramid using nested loops for homework. I am very new to nested loops and am still not quite clear on how they work completely. My objective is to make this pyramid using nested loops:

```
-----1----- 
----333---- 
---55555--- 
--7777777-- 
-999999999-
```

however I have only been able to get this:

```
----------1 
--------333-- 
------55555---- 
----7777777------ 
--999999999--------
```

I think I am on the right track but I am not sure where to go from here. 
Here is the code I currently have:

```
public class NumberPyramid

{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        for(int i=1; i<=9; i+=2)
        {
            for (int j = 11; j > i; j--)
            {
                System.out.print("-");
            }
            for(int j=1; j<=i; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(i);
            }
            for (int j = 1; j < i; j++)
            {
                System.out.print("-");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your input and output static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of printing the numbers in the center is correct.
Printing the `-` before and after the numbers is incorrect.

Notice that for any row, the number of `-` before and after the numbers should be the same. How many `-` to print for a number?

- For `1`, print 5 `-` before and after.
- For `3`, print 4 `-` before and after.
- For `5`, print 3 `-` before and after.

That's `(11 - i) / 2`. Put this loop before and after the center line and you're done.

```
for (int j = 0; j < (11 - i) / 2; j++) {
    System.out.print("-");
}
```

Comment: Ahhhhh got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should remove two `-` on every second line

```
int index = 5;
for (int i=1; i<=9; i+=2) {
    for (int j=0; j<index; j++) {
        System.out.print("-");
    }
    for (int k=0; k<i; k++) {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    for (int j=0; j<index; j++) {
        System.out.print("-");
    }
    System.out.println();
    index--;
}
```